# Interactive sliders in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, html, animations

Is it possible to make an interactive picture or animation with tikz which has an interactive slider?

The output format doesn't have to be pdf in this case, maybe also html or something else. The goal would just be:

- make a picture or better an animation with tikz
- add an slider where you can change some parameters and the picture or animation changes correspondingly.

It seems to be possible to have interactive sliders for pstricks pictures (at least if exported to html5): http://latex2html5.com/#sliders, but how is the case with tikz.

If it is possible it would be great if you could include a minimal working example of this (at best for a little animation).

Comment: That page says it is 'powered by MathJax' which is not TeX.

Comment: To do this kind of thing, I use `geogebra` which is natively designed to do this because it is written in javascript. https://www.geogebra.org